# Project.json frameworks confusing for EF class library

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core

I've seen the following frameworks listed in project.json:

- dotnet5.4
- net451
- dnx451
- net46

Which framework do I use for creating a new class library which makes use of the new latest EntityFramework (version 7)?
I've noticed some of these actually break the project and I get some errors so I'm not sure how the NuGet packages relate to which framework.

Comment: Can you please share what you have so far? (the project.json) Also, share the error that you get

Comment: I had a multitude of errors but I think it was my fault for not understanding the new naming conventions (dotnet, dnx, netstandard etc).  I still have problems with EF migrations but I have that warm in another SO post.  Do you know when the naming conventions will settle down? I feel excited to get going with the new stuff but also feel like abandoning it all until it decides to settle down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to read [.NET Platform Standard](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/architecture/net-platform-standard.md) to see where everything is headed.

`dotnet5.4` will be replaced by `netstandard1.3` which you can think of as `portable-net46+uap10.0+CoreCLR+etc.`

`dnx451` is going away. If you want to target .NET Framework 4.5.1, use `net451`.

Comment: I fixed it in the end by ensuring all project.json were set to dnx451. I thought 4.6.1 would be the latest version rather than 4.5.1?

Comment: ASP.NET Core supports back to .NET Frameork 4.5.1 because that's roughly equivalent to what Mono implements. ASP.NET Core can run on Mono.